# Optimizar clonar filas de una tabla html

Tags: jquery

Tengo una tabla de contactos en la cual cargo los datos vía jquery, esto funciona bien pero no me gusta el código lo encuentro poco optimo, quisiera me ayudaran a mejorarlo les dejo mi codigo

**Funcional**

```
            var fila_clon = $('#tbl-contactos-edita-proveedor tbody tr:first').clone();
            $('#tbl-contactos-edita-proveedor tbody tr').remove();
            $('#tbl-contactos-edita-proveedor tbody').append(fila_clon);
            $.each(retorna.contactos,function(indice, valor){
                var fila_clon = $('#tbl-contactos-edita-proveedor tbody tr:first').clone();
                fila_clon.find('.edita-nombre-contacto').each(function(){
                    $(this).val(valor.Con_Nombre).addClass('exlude');
                });
                fila_clon.find('.edita-fono-contacto').each(function(){
                    $(this).val(valor.Con_Fono).addClass('exlude');
                });
                fila_clon.find('.edita-correo-contacto').each(function(){
                    $(this).val(valor.Con_Correo).addClass('exlude');
                });
                $('#tbl-contactos-edita-proveedor tbody').append(fila_clon);
            });
            $('#tbl-contactos-edita-proveedor tbody tr:first').remove();
```

**Como pienso tendría que ser pero no funciona solo inserta la ultima fila del siclo each**

```
        var fila_clon = $('#tbl-contactos-edita-proveedor tbody tr:first').clone();
        $('#tbl-contactos-edita-proveedor tbody tr').remove();
        $.each(retorna.contactos,function(indice, valor){
            fila_clon.find('.edita-nombre-contacto').each(function(){
                $(this).val(valor.Con_Nombre).addClass('exlude');
            });
            fila_clon.find('.edita-fono-contacto').each(function(){
                $(this).val(valor.Con_Fono).addClass('exlude');
            });
            fila_clon.find('.edita-correo-contacto').each(function(){
                $(this).val(valor.Con_Correo).addClass('exlude');
            });
            $('#tbl-contactos-edita-proveedor tbody').append(fila_clon);
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta con llamar a fila_clon.clone() al pasarlo al append:

```
$('#tbl-contactos-edita-proveedor tbody').append(fila_clon.clone());
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes de pasarle la fila para como parametro de tu funcion, para que la fila este actualizada, cuando llamas a la funcion. Sino le estas pasando siempre la misma que iniciaste en la variable al principio.

```
$.each(retorna.contactos,function(indice, valor,fila_clon){
        fila_clon.find('.edita-nombre-contacto').each(function(){
            $(this).val(valor.Con_Nombre).addClass('exlude');
        });
        fila_clon.find('.edita-fono-contacto').each(function(){
            $(this).val(valor.Con_Fono).addClass('exlude');
        });
        fila_clon.find('.edita-correo-contacto').each(function(){
            $(this).val(valor.Con_Correo).addClass('exlude');
        });
        $('#tbl-contactos-edita-proveedor tbody').append(fila_clon);
    });
```

Comment: Pero de esta forma no puedo acceder a la propiedad `find`

Comment: ¿No bastaría con llamar a fila_clon.clone() al pasarlo al append? $('#tbl-contactos-edita-proveedor tbody').append(fila_clon.clone());

Comment: @JaviMollá eso funciono, podrías publicarlo como respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo con el comentario de Javi Mollá, la solución fue agregar `clone()` al pasar la variable al `append()` quedando `$('#tbl-contactos-edita-proveedor tbody').append(fila_clon.clone());`

```
            var fila_clon = $('#tbl-contactos-edita-proveedor tbody tr:first').clone();
            $('#tbl-contactos-edita-proveedor tbody tr').remove();
            if(retorna.contactos.length == 0){//en caso de no traer registros
                $('#tbl-contactos-edita-proveedor tbody').append(fila_clon);
            }
            $.each(retorna.contactos,function(indice, valor){
                fila_clon.find('.edita-nombre-contacto').each(function(){
                    $(this).val(valor.Con_Nombre).addClass('exlude');
                });
                fila_clon.find('.edita-fono-contacto').each(function(){
                    $(this).val(valor.Con_Fono).addClass('exlude');
                });
                fila_clon.find('.edita-correo-contacto').each(function(){
                    $(this).val(valor.Con_Correo).addClass('exlude');
                });
                $('#tbl-contactos-edita-proveedor tbody').append(fila_clon.clone());
            });
```